# Insert child node in XML

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

need help with simple inserting node after specific one in XML using Groovy. Searching through the existing posts came to that, closer but not enough

```
import groovy.xml.*

def x='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns7:setPlayerInfoRequest xmlns:ns7="http://www.playtech.com/services/player-management">
    <ns7:behaviourType>Create</ns7:behaviourType>
    <ns7:playerDataMap>
        <ns7:currency>${p_currency}</ns7:currency>
    </ns7:playerDataMap>
</ns7:setPlayerInfoRequest>'''

def n = '''<ns7:custom01>custom01</ns7:custom01>'''

def xml=new XmlParser().parseText(x)

def node = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(n)

def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name().localPart == 'currency' }

nodes.each{it.parent().appendNode(node)}

XmlUtil.serialize(xml).toString()
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns7:setPlayerInfoRequest xmlns:ns7="http://www.playtech.com/services/player-management">
  <ns7:behaviourType>Create</ns7:behaviourType>
  <ns7:playerDataMap>
    <ns7:currency>${p_currency}</ns7:currency>
    <custom01/>
  </ns7:playerDataMap>
</ns7:setPlayerInfoRequest>
```

Expected result is to have `<ns7:custom01>custom01</ns7:custom01>` inserted under parent playerDataMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use `XmlSlurper` to create `node` from `n`. But you should use `XmlParser` as you already do at the line above
2. You should also use `it.parent().append(node)` at the line with `nodes.each { it.parent().appendNode(node) }`

After applying these two changes, it will work as you expect